# How to fire a projectile in a certain direction with constant velocity (directX 9)

Tags: 2d, mathematics, directx

I am working on a top down 2d shooter.  I am trying to make the bullets go at a constant speed (in pixels) in the direction of the mouse.  I am having trouble doing this.  My bullets fire directly 45 degrees off where the mouse is.  I wrote this method which sets all the angles and rate of travel.
travelRate: Bullet speed in pixels per frame

targetX: target X coordinate in pixels

targetY: target Y coordinate in pixels

changeX: how far the bullet should go per frame along the X axis (in pixels)

changeY: how far the bullet should go per frame along the Y axis (in pixels)

ent:  The player/npc shooting the Projectile

I do not understand why my bullets are going at a 45 degree offset from the mouse.NOTE: I cut out some of the unimportant code from this method.

```
void Projectile::init(Entity * ent, int targX, int targY)
{
travelRate = 4;
setX(ent->getX());
setY(ent->getY());
targetX = targX;
targetY = targY;
float deltaY = getX()-targX;
float deltaX = getY()-targY;
float dLen = sqrt(deltaX*deltaX + deltaY*deltaY);
if (dLen == 0)
    dLen == 1;
deltaX /= dLen;
deltaY /= dLen;
float deg = rad * 180 / PI;
changeX = deltaX * travelRate;
changeY = -deltaY*travelRate;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
float deltaY = getX()-targX;
float deltaX = getY()-targY;
```

Could it be that you have mixed up deltaX and deltaY here?

Comment: Now it fires directly opposite.  But, i modified the method to say       
       changeX = -deltaX*travelRate;
 changeY = -deltaY*travelRate;  Now it works.  Thanks